# How do i convert collection of integer into list data type in python?

Tags: list, python-3.7

Say I have list of numbers like
12 23 445 656 76 75 86

How do I convert it into a list in python without manually typing each and seperating it with a comma?

Comment: So you've got a list and you want to convert it to a list?!

Comment: @ jonrsharpe  I have 30 different numbers and i want to make them into a list but i dont want to type those 30 different number one-by-one, i simply want to copy and paste in IDE but again i have to seperate them manually with a comma(,) which takes time so i wanted to know if there is any trick to do it quickly!
Sorry i am beginner so i may not be clear on things i want :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HERE IS A SIMPLE WAY OF DOING IT scan the numbers and then

```
ARR = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

this will convert the input given to stdin "separated by spaces" to a list.